# MLKit Barcode scan on iOS has wrong bounds/frame/cornerPoints coordinates

Tags: ios, google-mlkit

I followed the [guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/ios), and while it works on Android just fine, on iOS all the coordinates for scanned barcodes are wrong.

I'm not going to paste my whole code as it is the same as one from the guide.

The issue seems to be connected with the **orientation**. The provided coordinates would work fine if we can rotate and flip them. Or in other words: the provided coordinates appear to be in `.leftMirrored` orientation, while I'm holding the phone `.up`.

I tried to manually set orientation on `VisionImage` or `MLImage`. But changing orientation to any value there doesn't change anything. Almost like **setting orientation does nothing?**

```swift
  let mlImage = MLImage(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
  mlImage!.orientation = UIImage.Orientation.leftMirrored
      
      
//  let image = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
//  image.orientation = UIImage.Orientation.rightMirrored
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted to input your image into the ML Kit iOS sample application to check whether it is correctly detected?https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/ios